# List all the users logged in a specific group

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to Linux and Unix. I am not being able to figure out that
how to list all the logged in users from a specific group in Unix.

I spent a lot of time trying it. I know '  who ' command gives me the users logged in but I need to filter them by a specific group. 
Any help and tips please.

Comment: Search for a tutorial on how to perform basic UNIX-management.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: to be honest, I even finished one small book on Unix commands. I know shell scripting too but this particular group thing is nowhere mentioned in the book I read.

Comment: Can you list the users of a group? Can you know which users are logged in? If yes to both, and since you know shell, you got your answer :D

Comment: @Pawamoy I honestly do not know the answer to "Can you list the users of a group? "

Comment: @SamThapa I didn't either one minute ago. Just learned `/etc/group` on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, this is a painful exercise.  I've seen password and group files in production use that defy logic — but work.

For sake of concrete example, let's suppose you're interested in the logged-in members of the group `student`.

Now, the entry in the group database (`/etc/group` file, plus network resources) for a named group such as `student` may or may not have any members listed.  That doesn't necessarily mean there are no members in the group, though.  Each entry in the password database (`/etc/passwd` file, plus network resources) has a group number assigned, and the group number might be the same as the group number for group `student`, in which case that user belongs to the group too.

However, we're not done yet.  Suppose the entry in the group database reads:

```
student:x:2971:newton,einstein,socrates,plato
```

There might be other entries in the group database such as:

```
student_2020:x:2971:able,cain,adam,eve
```

Because this entry uses the same group number as group `student`, anyone who is listed in the `student_2020` entry is functionally a member of group `student` — the o/s kernel uses the number, not the name, to determine groups.

There can be sound reasons for splitting up group file entries; historically at least, some programs ran into problems if the list of names is too long.  That's bad programming, but when it is the system-provided software that does the crashing, you avoid triggering the crash.  Hence the multiple entries.

You can end up with multiple entries with different group numbers for the same group name (really confusing!) or with multiple names for the same group number (as above) or with multiple entries with the same group number and name.  It can be hit'n'miss as to what gets reported for any given name or number.

You can run into analogous problems in password files.  For example, multiple user names all with the same user number is sometimes used to allow multiple people root access (their user number is 0) but each has a separate password so some tracking is feasible.  However, it is generally better to use `sudo` these days — it was not always available, though.  Occasionally, there'll be a mistake and the same user name will appear twice with different user numbers.  Normally, the first entry in the file is used, but it can be confusing (at best).

However, it is not clear which programs you can use to analyze these issues, or derive a definitive answer about what is what.  If you search for the group by name (`getgrnam()` in C), then you typically get the first entry that matches that name (but it isn't necessarily clear whether that entry came from the network or the local file system).  If you search for the group by number (`getgrgid()` in C), then you typically get the first entry that matches that number.  However, if you scan the entire database with `setgrent()` plus repeated `getgrent()` plus `endgrent()` (optional), you might see all sorts of entries.

As a case in point, I can run this code on my Mac:

```
#include <grp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct group *grp;
    while ((grp = getgrent()) != 0)
    {
        printf("%5d %-15s", grp->gr_gid, grp->gr_name);
        char **mem = grp->gr_mem;
        char *pad = " -- ";
        while (*mem != 0)
        {
            printf("%s%s", pad, *mem++);
            pad = ", ";
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return(0);
}
```

When I do that and pipe the output through `sort -n`, I get (in parts):

```
   -2 nobody         
   -2 nobody         
   -1 nogroup        
   -1 nogroup        
    0 wheel           -- root
    0 wheel           -- root
    1 daemon          -- root
    1 daemon          -- root
    2 kmem            -- root
    2 kmem            -- root
    3 sys             -- root
    3 sys             -- root
    4 tty             -- root
    4 tty             -- root
    5 operator        -- root
    5 operator        -- root
    6 mail            -- _teamsserver
    6 mail            -- _teamsserver
    7 bin            
    7 bin            
…
   16 group          
   16 group          
   20 staff           -- root
   20 staff           -- root, informix, anonymous, supernumerary
   24 _networkd      
   24 _networkd    
…
```

Why the double entries?  Well, there's a file `/etc/group` which contains one set of entries — for example:

```
staff:*:20:root
```

There is also a database, Open Directory, that is consulted.  Indeed, the first lines of the `/etc/group` file on a Mac are comment lines (comments are not usually supported on other o/s) that read:

```
##
# Group Database
# 
# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
# in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
# Open Directory.
#
# See the opendirectoryd(8) man page for additional information about
# Open Directory.
##
```

There's a similar spiel at the top of the `/etc/passwd` file.  The Open Directory entry for `staff` lists 3 additional users.  What's curious is that when I run `id`, I'm also in group `staff`:

```
uid=501(jleffler) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),204(_developer),399(com.apple.access_ssh),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),100(_lpoperator),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
```

My name isn't even listed in `/etc/passwd`; it only appears in the Open Directory portion of the database.

And my name is only listed explicitly against groups 204 and 399 in the groups database; it is given group 20 in the password database; I'm not sure how groups 12, 61, 100, 701, 702 are associated with my user ID.  (And it is news to me that I don't know this — sometimes answering a question is educational for more people than the one who asked the question.)

So, as I noted at the start, it is not straight-forward to find the answer to your question.

If you scan the password database and groups database, you can get a reasonable approximation to the information you need, but you may never get the full answer unless you explore the controls on your platform.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49833188/15168) by [Abhishek Keshhri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486187/abhishek-keshri) suggests there is a (Linux-specific? — not on macOS, anyway) command `getent` that can be used to analyze the group database (and probably the user or password database, and maybe others too).  There are Open Directory tools on macOS to analyze the password and group databases on macOS.  You don't have to write and compile C code (but the code shown isn't rocket science).

Answer (score 1):

Use: `getent group group_name` to get users of a particular group, and `w` gives all logged in users. You can use these two to get your result.

While using `getent`, the fields, separated by `:`, are—

- Group name
- Encrypted password (not normally used)
- Numerical group ID
- Comma-separated list of members

Comment: hi,  when I type that command I get this,

mygroupname:x:120011:

Comment: the last parameter is the list of members

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below command. replace "test" with group name

users | xargs groups | grep test | awk -F: '{ print $1}'